# I have some features in mind about the perfect Linux OS: does elementary OS will answer to them?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, encryption

I would like to know if the latest version of Elementary OS allows to:

1. change the Mac address of the computer on each reboot
2. change the Mac address every x minutes
3. hide any folders (and subfolders) and protect their access with a password from a dedicated pack
4. add shortcut on the deskop (such as in windows)
5. ease the process to add a printer from well-known manufacturers (Canon, Epson, HP, etc.)

Thanks for these precisions.

Answer (score 0):

1. No.
2. No.
3. No.
4. No (can be accomplished with add-ons)
5. Varies drastically on the printer.